# Unable to connect Spring boot to consulMesos server

Tags: spring-boot, mesos, consul

Declared all the consul properties in `boostrap.properties`. Trying to run the application it fails to shutdown.

```
2019-05-07 14:49:34.323  INFO 12423 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : started _org.springframework.integration.errorLogger
2019-05-07 14:49:35.054  INFO 12423 --- [  restartedMain] b.c.PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration : Located property source: CompositePropertySource {name='consul', propertySources=[ConsulPropertySource {name='config/dataReflectorApp,cloud-dev/'}, ConsulPropertySource {name='config/dataReflectorApp/'}, ConsulPropertySource {name='config/application,cloud-dev/'}, ConsulPropertySource {name='config/application/'}]}
2019-05-07 14:50:31.823  WARN 12423 --- [  restartedMain] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'eventService': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is OperationException{statusCode=404, statusMessage='Not Found', statusContent=''}
2019-05-07 14:50:31.826  INFO 12423 --- [  restartedMain] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-05-07 14:50:31.840 ERROR 12423 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'eventService': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is OperationException{statusCode=404, statusMessage='Not Found', statusContent=''}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:139) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:414) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1754) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:849) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:139) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.DefaultBinderFactory.getBinderInstance(DefaultBinderFactory.java:291) [spring-cloud-stream-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.DefaultBinderFactory.doGetBinder(DefaultBinderFactory.java:192) [spring-cloud-stream-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.DefaultBinderFactory.getBinder(DefaultBinderFactory.java:130) [spring-cloud-stream-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService.getBinder(BindingService.java:337) [spring-cloud-stream-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService.bindProducer(BindingService.java:229) [spring-cloud-stream-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindableProxyFactory.createAndBindOutputs(BindableProxyFactory.java:287) [spring-cloud-stream-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.OutputBindingLifecycle.doStartWithBindable(OutputBindingLifecycle.java:58) [spring-cloud-stream-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedValues.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:608) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.AbstractBindingLifecycle.start(AbstractBindingLifecycle.java:48) ~[spring-cloud-stream-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.OutputBindingLifecycle.start(OutputBindingLifecycle.java:34) [spring-cloud-stream-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:182) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:53) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:360) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:158) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:122) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:893) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.finishRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:163) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:552) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at com.rccl.ncp.datareflector.DataReflectorApplication.main(DataReflectorApplication.java:14) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
Caused by: com.ecwid.consul.v1.OperationException: OperationException(statusCode=404, statusMessage='Not Found', statusContent='')
    at com.ecwid.consul.v1.event.EventConsulClient.eventList(EventConsulClient.java:76) ~[consul-api-1.4.1.jar:na]
    at com.ecwid.consul.v1.event.EventConsulClient.eventList(EventConsulClient.java:63) ~[consul-api-1.4.1.jar:na]
    at com.ecwid.consul.v1.ConsulClient.eventList(ConsulClient.java:423) ~[consul-api-1.4.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.cloud.consul.binder.EventService.getEventsResponse(EventService.java:80) ~[spring-cloud-consul-binder-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.consul.binder.EventService.init(EventService.java:59) ~[spring-cloud-consul-binder-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:363) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:307) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:136) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    ... 45 common frames omitted

2019-05-07 14:50:31.843  WARN 12423 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'outputBindingLifecycle'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'eventService': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is OperationException{statusCode=404, statusMessage='Not Found', statusContent=''}
2019-05-07 14:50:31.846  INFO 12423 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler          : Shutting down ExecutorService 'configWatchTaskScheduler'
2019-05-07 14:50:31.847  INFO 12423 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler          : Shutting down ExecutorService 'catalogWatchTaskScheduler'
2019-05-07 14:50:31.877  INFO 12423 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2019-05-07 14:50:31.879  INFO 12423 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler          : Shutting down ExecutorService 'taskScheduler'
2019-05-07 14:50:31.881  INFO 12423 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.i.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter   : Summary on shutdown: springCloudBusInput
2019-05-07 14:50:31.882  INFO 12423 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.i.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter   : Summary on shutdown: errorChannel
2019-05-07 14:50:31.882  INFO 12423 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.i.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter   : Summary on shutdown: springCloudBusOutput
2019-05-07 14:50:31.882  INFO 12423 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.i.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter   : Summary on shutdown: nullChannel
2019-05-07 14:50:31.882  INFO 12423 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.i.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter   : Summary on shutdown: _org.springframework.integration.errorLogger.handler
2019-05-07 14:50:31.882  INFO 12423 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.i.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter   : Summary on shutdown: org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.StreamListenerMessageHandler@5c282dd5
2019-05-07 14:50:31.898  INFO 12423 --- [  restartedMain] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-05-07 14:50:31.900 ERROR 12423 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'outputBindingLifecycle'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'eventService': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is OperationException{statusCode=404, statusMessage='Not Found', statusContent=''}
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:185) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:53) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:360) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:158) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:122) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:893) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.finishRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:163) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:552) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at com.rccl.ncp.datareflector.DataReflectorApplication.main(DataReflectorApplication.java:14) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'eventService': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is OperationException{statusCode=404, statusMessage='Not Found', statusContent=''}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:139) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:414) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1754) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:849) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:139) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.DefaultBinderFactory.getBinderInstance(DefaultBinderFactory.java:291) ~[spring-cloud-stream-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.DefaultBinderFactory.doGetBinder(DefaultBinderFactory.java:192) ~[spring-cloud-stream-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.DefaultBinderFactory.getBinder(DefaultBinderFactory.java:130) ~[spring-cloud-stream-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService.getBinder(BindingService.java:337) ~[spring-cloud-stream-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService.bindProducer(BindingService.java:229) ~[spring-cloud-stream-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindableProxyFactory.createAndBindOutputs(BindableProxyFactory.java:287) ~[spring-cloud-stream-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.OutputBindingLifecycle.doStartWithBindable(OutputBindingLifecycle.java:58) ~[spring-cloud-stream-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedValues.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:608) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.AbstractBindingLifecycle.start(AbstractBindingLifecycle.java:48) ~[spring-cloud-stream-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.OutputBindingLifecycle.start(OutputBindingLifecycle.java:34) ~[spring-cloud-stream-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:182) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.ecwid.consul.v1.OperationException: OperationException(statusCode=404, statusMessage='Not Found', statusContent='')
    at com.ecwid.consul.v1.event.EventConsulClient.eventList(EventConsulClient.java:76) ~[consul-api-1.4.1.jar:na]
    at com.ecwid.consul.v1.event.EventConsulClient.eventList(EventConsulClient.java:63) ~[consul-api-1.4.1.jar:na]
    at com.ecwid.consul.v1.ConsulClient.eventList(ConsulClient.java:423) ~[consul-api-1.4.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.cloud.consul.binder.EventService.getEventsResponse(EventService.java:80) ~[spring-cloud-consul-binder-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.consul.binder.EventService.init(EventService.java:59) ~[spring-cloud-consul-binder-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:363) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:307) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:136) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    ... 45 common frames omitted

Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:55668', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code 0
```

It run the spring boot application successfully and connection to consul/mesos should be established.

Comment: Can you share your configuration? You get 404

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to fix Consul URL as it says 404. If you haven't set up consul in local follow below steps:

1. download consul package from **https://www.consul.io/downloads.html**
2. Extract to folder
3. In case my case it is windows, cmd to **C:\Program Files (x86)\consul**
4. "**consul agent -dev**" - brings up consul
5. **http://localhost:8500/** - brings up consul UI
6. check properties as below.
   cloud:
   consul:
     host: http://localhost
     port: 8500
     config:
       enabled: false
       fail-fast: true
7. re-start spring boot application